# How to deploy war application build with grails 3 on tomcat 8?

Tags: tomcat, grails

I want to deploy an war application built with grails 3.0.11.

I'm trying to deploy this war on tomcat 8.0.30 (I'm not sure that is a right version for grails 3).

When I try to deploy the application I have this error on catalina.out log file.

```
Deploying web application archive /home/utente/apache-tomcat-    8.0.30/webapps/szzz.war
25-Jan-2016 09:55:24.710 INFO [localhost-startStop-1]   org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned   for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a   complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them.   Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
25-Jan-2016 09:55:24.763 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive /home/utente/apache-tomcat-8.0.30/webapps/szzz.war has finished in 5,397 ms
```

Comment: Where exactly is the error message? Do you refer to the `TldScanner` info line?

Comment: This is not an error, only an info. The real error is probably later in the log.

Comment: You're right ! the problem was due to a wrong java version: i was using java 7 instead java 8 ! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I would say try tomcat 8.0.36 -